# GStreamer pipeline wont preroll

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

Hi guys im trying to setup Gstreamer between my Pi and a windows computer. My comands are:

Pi:

```
~ raspivid -n -w 1280 -h 720 -b 1000000 -fps 15 -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=[IP] port=9000
```

PC:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=9000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=f
```

I get the error:

```
sudo: /home/pi: command not found
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0: No valid frames found before end of stream
Additonal debug info:
gst_base_parse_sink_event_default (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Any help would be great thanks!!

Comment: check the first line of error output - command not found - what is happening there? I do not see any sudo.. btw I guess there is no sudo on RPI

Answer (score 1):

(He just omitted the sudo in the line, but he actually typed it).
His home directory is /home/pi, and ~expands to /home/pi.
~ raspivid -n -w 1280 -h 720 -b 1000000 -fps 15 -t 0 -o -
expands to 
/home/pi raspivid -n -w 1280 -h 720 -b 1000000 -fps 15 -t 0 -o -
Thus the "command not found", since /home/pi is not an executable. The result of this erroneous command is piped to gst-launch-1.0 and, of course, there are no valid frames!